# I need to move my computor from one side of the room to another. Do I need to close everything and shut it down first?

Tags: imac

I need to move my imac computer from one side of the room to the other.  Do I need to close everything and shut it down first?

Comment: This must be a desktop computer or you would not even need to ask. You are going to have to unplug the desktop and plug it in on the other side of the room. It likely has a hard drive that will not be receptive to a jiggling move on the fly.  So yes, you need to close up and shut down first.

Comment: I havent used a mac in ages, do macs have hibernate?

Comment: @Keltari - they have various stages of sleep to full hibernate, but these mainly rely on power being maintained & therefore most use on laptops. On a desktop it's not really worth it. They come back up in the same state they were shut down anyway, for all apps that are toolbox compliant. You don't even need to save your work, it's all stored in special saved state & auto save functions which run continuously & double-check at shut down or reboot. Very unlike Windows which has a true hibernate mode saving the entire RAM to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this is a good idea, however if the power cable is long enough and you are using an SSD you can move it while its on.

The main risks are -

- You will dislodge the power cable causing a sudden shutdown and risk some data loss.  With modern systems and journaling filesystems this risk is very small - same risk if you don't have a UPS and there is a power outage.
- **if you have an old style spinning hard drive** you are risking damaging it because of extra vibration/knocks while it us spinning.  There is a risk of permanent data loss.  The risk is not massive  but not negligible either. **This risk does not apply to SSD's** as they don't have moving parts.
- There us a risk if dislodging a cable, which could cause a confused state  This risk us not much higher then the risks  of knocking out the power cable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't risk upsetting anything by moving it whilst switched on. If you don't need to unplug the mains to move it, you *could* get away with it, but it's not worth the risk.

All you need to do is go to the  menu & select Shut Down…
This will present you with a dialog

[image]

Make sure that box is checked, then click Shut Down. You don't need to Quit apps first. They will come back exactly where you left them next time you start the Mac up.
The only exceptions are any apps which present you any type of "Save before you Quit?" dialog, which means they are not Apple toolbox compliant & must be specifically saved, then re-opened after next boot.
Adobe apps behave this way.

All Apple apps will just automatically store just exactly where you left off whether you saved your documents or not. The state is preserved.